# SwiftUI ForEach Text padding adds additional spacing below the elements

Tags: swift, swiftui

Adding a padding to the `Text(name)` element results in some additional spacing below the each name (John-spacing-Chris-spacing-Mary-spacing-Thomas) while iterating using `ForEach`. Is this a bug in SwiftUI ? How to remove this spacing ?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var names = ["John", "Chris", "Mary", "Thomas"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(names, id: \.self) { (name) in
            ///adds weird padding between the entries
            Text(name).padding(16).background(Color.green)
        }
        ForEach(names, id: \.self) { (name) in
            ///this is fine
            Text(name).padding(0).background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use VStack with zero spacing

Comment: @swiftPunk thanks, enclosing the ForEach in VStack with no spacing did the trick. Is it because the SwiftUI uses a VStack with a default spacing of 8 which enlcoses the result of the ForEach ?

Comment: Correct! SwiftUI default has always spacing.